# Not able to set read-only property in CFile in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am creating a file which will have some details in it, and I don't want anybody to be able to edit it.
So, I decided to keep it as a read-only file. I tried the following code but it's popping up an exception when I set the status.

Please tell me if there's an alternative solution.

Here's my code:

```
CFile test(L"C:\\Desktop\\myText.txt",CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite);
CFileStatus status;
test.GetStatus(status);
status.m_attribute = CFile::readonly;
test.SetStatus(L"C:\\Desktop\\myText.txt",status);
```

Comment: What's the exception? What's it say in the event log?

Comment: "Encountered a sharing violation while accessing "C:\\Desktop\\myText.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the following:

1. Close the file before changing the status with a call to `CFile::Close()` (`test.Close()` in your example.)
2. OR in the readonly attribute with the existing attributes, e.g. `status.m_attribute |= CFile::readonly`.